# Searching for a certain field of an Object in a linked list C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

```
int Search(int x) {
        Node* temp = head;
        int pos = 1;
        while(temp != nullptr){
            if(temp->data == x)
                return pos;
            else{
                temp=temp->next;
                pos++;
            }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

This search function is used in order to search for an integer within a linked list that I have created and return the location of the integer. I am now working with a Linked List that involves Person objects with four fields: name, age, height, and weight. How would I go about writing a Search function to search for a user by their name and then printing out the whole Person once found? I tried writing this, but it would not work:

```
Person Search(Person*A) {
        Node* temp = head;
        int pos = 1;
        while(temp != nullptr){
            if(temp->data == A)
                return *A;
            else{
                temp=temp->next;
                pos++;
            }
        }
        return *A;
}
```

Finally I figured that I needed setters/getters for name and I would need to pass the Parameter Search(Person.getName()), but this was throwing an error as well. Can someone explain to me how to do this? I have not found anything similar to this online so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you implemented the  `==` comparison operator for `Person`?

Comment: So you posted the code that you've abandoned but didn't post the code you are currently working with? How do you expect any help when you don't post your code?

Comment: @john The current code I am trying is the Person Search posted above.

Comment: @codekaizer where would I put that? I am using a pointer to Person A and checking if the data in the temp node is == to A?

Comment: @Fall0ut You haven't posted your `Person` class, you haven't posted the code where you call `Search`

Comment: You probably have errors in all these places. You really need to post more code.

Comment: @codekaizer implementing `operator==` for the Person class would probably be wrong, because the OP is searching for the person by name.

Comment: @john no I know the rest of my code is correct. It is all working properly with all my other functions. Plus we are always told to keep it minimal on here and this is all that needs to be fixed.

Comment: @Fallout minimal and **complete**, if minimal was the only consideration you wouldn't post any code at all. Anyway I've given up. Question cannot possibly be answered in the current form.

Comment: @Fall0ut I know the rest of my code is correct, I really really doubt that, but maybe you know best.

Comment: @john, yeah if OP searches by name in his statement `Search(Person.getName())`, however function is `Search(Person *)`. conflicting types

Comment: @codekaizer ahh okay I see what youre saying. Yes I already overloaded that operator.

Comment: @codekaizer The OP said he used `Person.getName()` but that obviously incorrect because Person is a type. But as he said, the rest of his code is correct.

Comment: @john, yeah! rest of this code is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think that the search function is like the following code:

```
Person* Search(std::string search_name) {
        Node* temp = head;
        while(temp != nullptr){
            if(temp->data->name == search_name){ //compare name
                return temp->data;
            }
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        return nullptr;
}
```

Input the name you want to search，the function will return the person pointer

Comment: I'd rather return `new Person()` than `nullptr`. just my practice though.

Comment: Yes! This worked! Easier than I expected. I did not realize I could use temp->data->name  to access just the name field. I am rather new to C++ so this was a major help. Much appreciation.

Comment: @codekaizer is there anyway to return a string such as "No Person with that name was in the list"?

Comment: @codekaizer Then how do you determine whether the search was successful?

Comment: @Fall0ut You can print a message after you used this function and it returned a null pointer. Keep data processing and user interaction separated.

Comment: @molbdnilo got it! Thank you so much everyone.

Comment: @molbdnilo,  `name` would be an empty string and the rest of other class members are also empty. This way, user of the `Search()` would be just focused on the `Person` class and not worried about `null`

Comment: @molbdnilo, purely hypothetical since `Person` class is not shared by OP

Comment: @codekaizer Thanks for your advice.But if I return new Person(),the user must delete this pointer I create

Comment: @Gleipnir, either way if search is successful or not, `Person` should always be deleted. right? :)

Comment: @codekaizer if search is successful and user delete the pointer,the linked list will be broke.T_T

Comment: @Gleipnir, I'm not saying `Person` will be deleted right away when search is successful.

As I've said, it's a matter of preference. You can read more about the discussion in this forum: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/120355/is-it-better-to-return-null-or-empty-values-from-functions-methods-where-the-ret

Comment: @ codekaizer I am interested in your advice. And I get some Heuristic ideas from the forum. Thank you verry much. :)